# Difficulty Importing Fonts in Python FPDF package

Tags: python, fpdf

I'm having a tough time trying to get something working which I think should be straightforward.

I'm new to python and learning via projects which in this case is a simple PDF generator. I want to add custom fonts to my program (Poppins) and I can get it to work if I include the fonts in the exact location as main.py, but ideally, I want these stored in a separate folder.

I've tried numerous suggestions but nothing has worked for me yet. Such as:

- appending/inserting the font filepath to sys.path ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder))
- creating an `__init__.py` file in the main directory with the following

```
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(1, '.')
```

- Also tried a blank `__init__.py` file in the font directory

I've attached a screenshot of my code below along with the error message. Thanks in advance for any support.
[image: My python code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the add_font [documentation of FPDF](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/add_font/index.html):

Note: the font source files must be accessible. They are searched successively in (if these constants are defined):

`FPDF_FONTPATH` (by default, the font folder in the fpdf package directory)

`SYSTEM_TTFONTS` (e.g. C:\WINDOWS\FONTS)